# How to get a real number list from foreach?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Using the `...` notation outputs integers as `2` instead of `2.0`. The first integer is treated as it is written, but the ones onward won't have their `.0` unless the `...` is dropped.

What's the way to obtain a list of real numbers?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {0.5,1,...,3} {\x\ }

\foreach \x in {0.5,1.0,...,3} {\x\ }

\foreach \x in {0.5,1.0,...,3.0} {\x\ }

\foreach \x in {0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0} {\x\ }

\end{document}
```

[image: Output from code.]

Comment: This is intended. See `pgffor.code.tex` line 349-353. You can change this behavior by redefining `\pgffor@strip`.

Comment: Found the file but couldn't understand a thing from it. I'll write all the numbers for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these lines after Ti*k*Z is included.

```
\makeatletter
\def\pgffor@strip#1.0{\def\pgffor@temp{#1.0}}
\makeatother
```